# LEGO set from these two structures

Tags: set-identification

Got these but could not identify the set.[image]

Comment: Please stop using the lego group tag for every single question you post, if you want a set to be identified you can use set- identification tag or for a single part(s) use part-identification. I have edited your post to make this change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like [Border Ambush (8778)](https://brickset.com/sets/8778-1/Border-Ambush):

[image: set box]